# How to get all my playlists with SoundCloud API

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, soundcloud

I'm using the iOS SDK provided by SoundCloud. My issue is the following : i can't get my playlists. Indeed, there a few weeks, everything was working properly but now my jsonResponse object is nil.
Here is an excerpt of my code :

```
//Get soundcloud account to launch request
SCAccount *account = [SCSoundCloud account];
SCRequestResponseHandler handler;
handler = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    NSJSONSerialization *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                         JSONObjectWithData:data
                                         options:0
                                         error:&jsonError];
    if (!jsonError && [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        //response treatment
    }

NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/playlists.json";
[SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
              onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:resourceURL]
         usingParameters:nil
             withAccount:account
  sendingProgressHandler:nil
         responseHandler:handler];
```

I don't understand because the two following requests return results:

1. /Me (about my soundcloud account)

NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/me.json";
Request with this URL return an NSDictionary which contains some informations such as the number of playlists (return 61 playlists)

2. /Tracks (get tracks)

NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json";
Request with this URL return an NSArray which contains some informations about my tracks

So, i am wondering if the url to get all playlists of my account with soundcloud api would not have changed ? 
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since SoundCloud decided not to maintain anymore this library I created my own one, maybe it could helps you. One of the request I've already implemented is request your playlists:

```
[self.soundCloudPort requestPlaylistsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *playLists) {
    // Here you have your playlists
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // Handle the error
}];
```

[ABMSoundCloud on Github](https://github.com/andresbrun/ABMSoundCloudAPI)